# Why does JS report 'this.function' as not being a function?

Tags: javascript, this

I wonder if somebody could please help me understand something that seems odd with JS?

The below code works. The function `inlineEditEvent.init()` is called, and then `t.copy()` is called correctly (where `var t = this;`).

However, if I was to replace that with `this.copy()`, I get the error `this.copy is not a function`.

What's the difference here? Why does the below work, but not the way as described in the last paragraph? Thanks.

```
jQuery(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){inlineEditEvent.init();});

    inlineEditEvent = {

        init : function(){

            var t = this;

            /** Copy the row on click */
            $('#the-list').on('click', '.row-actions a.single-copy', function(){
                return t.copy();
            });

        }, // init

        copy : function(){

            // Do stuff here

        }

    } // inlineEditEvent

});
```

Comment: `this` is not a lexically scoped identifier. Its value is determined entirely on how its enclosing function was invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to `this` within the functions scope. That's why you need to set a `self` variable, so it's accessible within the scope of the function. Considering you're using jQuery, you could use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$.proxy(function(){
    return this.copy();
},this)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `t` as a context variable of `this` (of your `init` function). Once inside your click handler, `this` is now referring to the click handler, no longer the `init` function. Therefore, `this.copy()` is not a function.

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the click handler, nor to the `init` function. That's not how `this` works in JS.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I was thinking it was as with PHP (for example) where it referred to the Class like object.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `var t= this;` it refers to what `this` meant in that context. Later on when you are trying to refer to this, it is referring to `a.single-copy` instead since that is the new context it is in.

Comment: Later `this` is _not_ referring to `$('#the-list')`, or to any jQuery object. In that particular part of the code `this` is referring to the `a.single-copy` DOM element that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

`t.copy();` appears in a *different function* to `var t = this;`. The value of `this` changes inside each function.